# Install Skype on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-center, skype

How can I install Skype on Ubuntu 14.04 with synaptic? I don't want to download from the site

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! It is very nice that you want to help others, but here we like Questions to have Answers. Could you reformat this so that it is a question, and then answer it with your information!

Comment: @Tim @"Kauko Peltonen"  I agree with Tim

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answered in Question

> Open 'System Settings'. Under 'Ubuntu programs' choose the following 3
> sources:
>
> 1. ' Free and open source programs packed by Canonical (main)' ;
> 2. 'Free and open source programs   supported by community (universe)'
> 3. ' Programs restricted by copyright and legal issues (multiverse)'
>
> Under 'Other programs' choose the following 3
>
> 1. 'Canonical partners, applications of partners packed by Canonical' ;
> 2. 'Independent, Applications of other developers'
> 3. 'Independent (source code), Applications of other developers';
>
> Open Software Update by searching the dash and update it.
>
> Install Synaptic Package Manager with this command:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install synaptic
> ```
>
> or by searching the Software Center for Synaptic
>
> Search for skype and right click. Choose mark for Installation and the click Apply.
>
> Now your installation is finished, test it!

Comment: Tim hi, this new text is excellent work ! One addition, if possible: Synaptic application can be installed also from 'Ubuntu Application Selection' (correct name in English ??) just by writing 'Synaptic' and clicking it for installation.  Brsgs, Kauko

Comment: @KaukoPeltonen Pleasure :) I take it you realise why I edited the question and put it into an answer - this page may explain more http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?

Comment: Tim hi, excellent ! Could you or someone forward this new edited text for those who make / issue Ubuntu iser instructions, so that other persons - perhaps - couild utilize this ''click - click'' installation method in case they hesitate to utilize terminal installation method.  I do not know how to do it. Brds, Kauko

Comment: One more possible addtion to this text might be: ''After your testing is OK, you can add skype-pigin and skype-empathy packages with Synaptic later to your Skype in case you want to have Pigin and Empahty features also.'' Brgds, Kauko